# How to save the return value of a function attached to a tkinter Button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, tkinter

#### Background info

I am writing a set of tools to crack Vigenere cipher for a school project. There is a problem that I know I can solve if I could pass pointers like in C but I started this in Python and I don't want to rewrite everything. Code is on https://github.com/DarkFireGuy/cracking-vigenere if you want to see

#### The Problem

`freq_analysis.py` has a function `_plot()` that is used to plot and save the image. After pyplot has created the graph I check to see if the file has an extension. If it doesn't then I call `simple_popup()` from `tools.py` (small collection of nifty little functions). This call sends three pieces of information to a function that makes it easier for me to simplify tkinter use:

1. A message to tell the user that the file name is bad and doesn't have an extension,
2. Button labels to tell the user which one does what.
3. Functions to tell each button what they're supposed to do.

If the user presses the button to enter a new name I would call `simple_popup_input()` (not written yet) to take the new input. But I cannot do that until I figure out how I would get the input into the `fext` (file extension). For now I am using exec to take user input and putting it into `fext` (txt on cml no fancy pants tkinter yet) but this `fext` is not the same `fext` from before. To fix all of this I need to be to write to the address at which `fext` is located. Google told me it wasn't possible in python so I have come to the council of smart people to see what I should do.

#### Solutions?

1. Rewrite the whole thing in C
2. Figure out how to get the memory address of `fext`
3. (just came to me while writing this) write the new file extension to a temporary file and then read it after the `simple_popup_input()` call --- Don't want to do this because there has be a more elegant solution
4. Don't know how it would work but to include two tuples which will contain arguments that get passed into `func1` and `func2`. `simple_popup` header would become:

   ```
   def simple_popup(message="Error", f1=lambda: True, f2=lambda: True, args1: tuple = (),
                    args2: tuple = (), option1: str = "Yes", option2: str = "No")
   ```

`req_analysis.py` problematic code snippet:

```
# Rename file if it does not contain an extension
output, fext = os.path.splitext(output)
if not fext:
    simple_popup(message="The file name you have chosen does not contain an extension",
                 f1=lambda: exec("fext = str(input(\"New extension: \"))"),
                 option1="Enter new name",
                 option2="Save without extension"
                     )
output = output+fext
print(output)
```

`tools.py` problematic code snippet:

```
def simple_popup(message="Error",
                 f1=lambda: True,
                 f2=lambda: True,
                 option1: str = "Yes",
                 option2: str = "No"):

    def func1():
        f1()
        popup.quit()


    def func2():
        f2()
        popup.quit()

    popup = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(popup, text=message)
    button1 = tk.Button(popup, text=option1, command=func1)
    button2 = tk.Button(popup, text=option2, command=func2)

    for tmp in [label, button1, button2]:
        tmp.pack()

    popup.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you looked at `functools`, like `wraps` or `partial` for point 4?

Comment: Please watch your language when using this site.

Comment: @martineau sorry, won't happen again. I was following along with the voice in my head and didn't even realize what I did

Comment: @ahed87 No I did not but the approved answer is a much better way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. Your question should be "Is there a better way to do this?". There is. Use a `messagebox`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

root = tk.Tk()

path = r'C:\Some\Path'
_, ext = os.path.splitext(path)

if not ext and not messagebox.askyesno('Missing Extension', 'Save without extension?'):
    #the user may provide a dot ~ strip it out and rely on our static dot
    path = f"{path}.{input('submit new extension: ').lstrip('.')}"
          
print(path)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show how I would take the input with Tkinter? I tried to do that but the first popup would not disappear when the input popup came up.

Comment: And what is meant by r in ```r'C:\Some\Path'``` and f in ```f"{path}..."```

Comment: @DarkFireGuy: The `r` string prefix stands for "raw" and suppresses the normal backslash escaping that occurs in string literals— i.e `"\n"` being replaced by a newline. Backslashes are what Windows natively uses separate components in file system paths.